# Access instance variable from within an object inside of an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   // I want to return a new object which has access to this.x and this.y

   // For example:
   return {
      addTwo: function() {
         // How can I access this.x from the MyObj instance?
         return 2 + (x from the instance of MyObj)
      }
   }
};
```

How can I return an object from the example method so that it has access to the instance variables from an instance of MyObj?

I can't use 'this' inside the returning object, or else it will refer to the object that I am returning.

And I am not using es6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't state if you can use es6 or not. Basically it's a problem of scope. With es6 and babel you can do something like

## ES6 Method

```
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   // I want to return a new object which has access to this.x and this.y

   // For example:
   return {
      addTwo: () => {
         // How can I access this.x from the MyObj instance?
         return 2 + this.x
      }
   }
};
```

In this way `this` won't change as arrow functions are having `this` context inherited from outer scope.

**For the reference**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Which is basically transpiled to something like this (You are not using classes so I assume you are not using es6)

## Old way method

```
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   // I want to return a new object which has access to this.x and this.y

   var that = this
   // For example:
   return {
      addTwo: function(){
         // How can I access this.x from the MyObj instance?
         return 2 + that.x
      }
   }
};
```

which will just "store" `this` variable to other variable for later usage (that's what similarly babel does under the cover).

## .bind() method

If you wanna 3rd answer you can bind `this` context to a called function as this

```
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   // I want to return a new object which has access to this.x and this.y

   var addTwo = function() {
     return 2 + this.x
   }
   // For example:
   return {
      addTwo: addTwo.bind(this)
   }
};
```

which will "transfer" `this` to that function.

**For the reference**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

The are a few options - the simplest would be to create a reference to `this` of your `MyObj` instance and refer to that in the `addTwo()` function of the object that `example()` returns like so:

```js
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   
   // Create local variable to this, called self
   let self = this;
   
   return {
      addTwo: function() {
      
         // Access self field, which is reference 
         // to instance of enclosing object
         return 2 + (self.x);
      }
   }
};

var obj = new MyObj(5);

console.log('should return 5 + 2:', obj.example().addTwo() );

obj.x = 10;

console.log('should return 10 + 2:', obj.example().addTwo() );
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you briefly explain the other options? The ones without creating a local variable to 'this'?

Answer (score 0):

If you use arrow functions the `this` context won't change inside:

```js
var MyObj = function(x) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = 5;
};

MyObj.prototype.example = function() {
   return {
      addTwo: () => 2 + this.x
   }
};

const o = new MyObj(2);
console.log(o.example().addTwo());
```